# Accessing custom properties inside multiCapabilities config object

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I have a custom property `screenSize` in a multiCapabilities config property like so:

```
multiCapabilities: [{
    browserName: 'chrome',
    screenSize: 'large',
    chromeOptions : {
      args: [
        '--start-maximized'
      ]
    },
    shardTestFiles: true
  }, {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    screenSize: 'medium',
    chromeOptions : {
      args: [
        '--window-size=960,1000']
    },
    shardTestFiles: true
  }]
```

I want to be able to access this property during my tests, as it will determine what elements need to be clicked on during each test run.

In a beforeAll() within a test suite I am trying to run I have the following:

```
browser.getCapabilities().then(function(caps) {
        console.log(caps);
        screenSize = caps.get('screenSize');
        console.log('SCREEN SIZE IS - ' + screenSize.toUpperCase());
      });
```

The value of caps when logged out is:

```
[chrome #11] Capabilities {
[chrome #11]   'acceptSslCerts' => true,
[chrome #11]   'applicationCacheEnabled' => false,
[chrome #11]   'browserConnectionEnabled' => false,
[chrome #11]   'browserName' => 'chrome',
[chrome #11]   'chrome' => { chromedriverVersion: '2.25.426923 (0390b88869384d6e
b0d5d09729679f934aab9eed)',
[chrome #11]   userDataDir: 'C:\\Users\\rparker\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\scoped_di
r12912_15516' },
[chrome #11]   'cssSelectorsEnabled' => true,
[chrome #11]   'databaseEnabled' => false,
[chrome #11]   'handlesAlerts' => true,
[chrome #11]   'hasTouchScreen' => false,
[chrome #11]   'javascriptEnabled' => true,
[chrome #11]   'locationContextEnabled' => true,
[chrome #11]   'mobileEmulationEnabled' => false,
[chrome #11]   'nativeEvents' => true,
[chrome #11]   'networkConnectionEnabled' => false,
[chrome #11]   'pageLoadStrategy' => 'normal',
[chrome #11]   'platform' => 'Windows NT',
[chrome #11]   'rotatable' => false,
[chrome #11]   'takesHeapSnapshot' => true,
[chrome #11]   'takesScreenshot' => true,
[chrome #11]   'version' => '55.0.2883.87',
[chrome #11]   'webStorageEnabled' => true }
```

So as can be seen, my additional property is not available here.

How can I get at it? Is this possible?

On another note (sorry this should be another question), I notice that two test runs are performed at the same time, one for each screen size I have defined in the args options. I take it this is default behaviour when multiple configs are defined? Can you make these run sequentially rather than parallel?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have answer to your second question

Q2: Can you make these run sequentially rather than parallel?
A2: Yes, As the below extract says, the option `shardTestFiles` decides whether the tests run in parallel. For full [documentation refer here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts#L275)

```
  /**
     * If this is set to be true, specs will be sharded by file (i.e. all
     * files to be run by this set of capabilities will run in parallel).
     * Default is false.
     */
    shardTestFiles?: boolean;
```